# JSON-LD multiple types

Tags: markup, json-ld

I am currently doing some json-ld. I am quite new to this(also with coding). I am trying to figure it out how could I use different Types in one script, as you can see below. I cannot get a hold onto what am I doing wrong and what should I change to make it work? Thanks

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Course",
    "name": "MSc in IT- Web Communication Design",
    "coursePrerequisites": "The following bachelor degree programmes from the University of Southern Denmark and from other universities provide access to the Master’s degree in Web Communication Design: A relevant professional bachelor's degree, e.g. web developer, software developer, business language and IT-based marketing communication, school teacher, nurse, educator, social worker.",
    "occupationalCredentialAwarded": "As a student of the MSc in IT – Web Communication Design you will gain specialised skills in web-based communication and knowledge management. Your choice of elective courses, your projects, your thesis as well as your bachelor background qualify you to work with: Web development, digitalisation, web design, digital skills development, social media, etc.",
    "description":"Master of Science in IT Web Communication Design. A multi-disciplinary graduate programme that combines IT, communication and organisation. We emphasise the interaction between humans and information technology and combine research-based knowledge with challenges from practice."
},

"provider": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "University of Southern Denmark",
    "department": "Institute for Design and Communication",
    "address": "Universitetsparken 1, 6000 Kolding, Denmark",
    "telephone": "+45 65 50 10 00"
    
},

{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EducationalOccupationalCredential",
    "programPrerequisites": "You are expected to have basic knowledge of HTML and CSS before you commence the programme. This may be from courses in your Bachelor's, but it is also possible to obtain this knowledge through online tutorials, e.g. w3schools.com."

    

}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that validates:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Course",
  "name": "MSc in IT- Web Communication Design",
  "coursePrerequisites": "You are expected to have basic knowledge of HTML and CSS before you commence the programme. This may be from courses in your Bachelor's, but it is also possible to obtain this knowledge through online tutorials, e.g. w3schools.com.",
  "occupationalCredentialAwarded": "As a student of the MSc in IT – Web Communication Design you will gain specialised skills in web-based communication and knowledge management. Your choice of elective courses, your projects, your thesis as well as your bachelor background qualify you to work with: Web development, digitalisation, web design, digital skills development, social media, etc.",
  "description": "Master of Science in IT Web Communication Design. A multi-disciplinary graduate programme that combines IT, communication and organisation. We emphasise the interaction between humans and information technology and combine research-based knowledge with challenges from practice.",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "University of Southern Denmark",
    "department": "Institute for Design and Communication",
    "address": "Universitetsparken 1, 6000 Kolding, Denmark",
    "telephone": "+45 65 50 10 00"
  }
}</script>
```

The script expects one top level object, not a list of objects. To get around it you can use @graph. My changes meant there is only one top object anyhow.

This is because you want to connect your information. The organization is the provider of the course, so that information should be in the course object.

I wasn't sure about your EducationalOccupationalCredential. I'm guessing a coursePrerequisites is closer to what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Tony McCreath! I suppose the reason why EducationalOccupationalCredential does not belong here because it is a type itself and not a property of the Course type. At least that is how i understood it :)

Comment: Yes, and I could not see an obvious way to reference it from a course. No property could accept that type. It also did not seem to match what the text implied you were talking about.